# Activity starts each time call is received even after App is closed?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

In my application , there is an activity which is launched if a call is recieved using this code:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            incall = true;
        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (incall) {

                c = TestOnDemo.this;
                Intent i = new Intent(TestOnDemo.this,
                        IncallActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);
                incall = false;

            }

        } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            incall = true;
        } else if (state == 0) {
            // Incoming call: Pause music
            incall = true;
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (mgr != null) {
    mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

This works fine -After the call ends specific Activity is launched. But there is a problem 
when my App is not running or is not at foreground and receives a call.After the call ends the activity is launched again.Can any one help me.Thanks?

Comment: You should stop your service when your activity gets destroyed. You can also bind the service to your activity.You need to explicitly stop your service else the service will keep on running.

Comment: I am directly using this code snippet in activity ..I am not using service

Comment: Please unregister your  PhoneStateListener when your activity gets finished.